# Filtering SQL data by ListBox item to display in DataGridViews

Tags: vb.net

I can't get the listbox item to filter properly.

Basically, I want to click an item in my ListBox and that will populate the DataGridView accordingly. I have 2 DataGridViews which will display different criteria based on the ListBox item selected.

My code so far is the following:

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim str As String = "Data Source=XXXXX;Initial Catalog=XXXXXX;Integrated Security=True"
    Dim con As New SqlConnection(Str)
    Dim com As String = "Select swname, numoflic from SW2"
    Dim com2 As String = "Select name, instdate, swinsta, organ from Assigned2"
    Dim Adpt As New SqlDataAdapter(com, con)
    Dim Adpt2 As New SqlDataAdapter(com2, con)
    Dim ds, ds2 As New DataSet()

Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim dt As DataTable
    dt = New DataTable("SW2")

    'DEFINING LISTBOX ITEM AS STRING
    Dim curItem As String = ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()

    ds.Tables.Clear()
    ds2.Tables.Clear()

    Adpt.Fill(ds, "ContactPerson2")
    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)

    Adpt2.Fill(ds2, "Assigned2")
    DataGridView2.DataSource = ds2.Tables(0)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to filter your data set as explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b51xae2y(v=vs.71).aspx).  Also, I'd recommend you don't refill your datatables in the event handler.  Load them both in Form_Load and then just pass Nothing to the filter to clear any prior filters in the beginning of the SelectedIndexChanged event handler.

Comment: Thanks for the help! It was very useful. I will post my solution. I changed the code around a bit

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code around a bit and what works for me now is the code below.

```
    Dim curItem As String = ListBox1.SelectedItem(1)
    Dim sqlConnectionString As String = "Data Source=XXXX;Initial Catalog=XXXXX;Integrated Security=True"
    Dim sqlSelect As String = "Select swname, number from SW"
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(sqlSelect, sqlConnectionString)
    Dim dt As New DataTable

    da.Fill(dt)

    'filter setting defined here
    Dim filter As String = "swname = '" + curItem + "'"

    'filter rows
    Dim FilteredRows As DataRow() = dt.Select(filter)

    For Each row As DataRow In FilteredRows
        DataGridView1.DataSource = FilteredRows.CopyToDataTable()

    Next
```